# Disable Facebook Comments Automatically On CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, publish

I am working with the Facebook comments plugin.  I have a custom post type that never uses Facebook comments.  I am trying to create a function to automatically turn these off when the custom post type is published.

In the database there is a meta key called **_disable_fbc** and it accepts two values.  Having the meta_value as **on** turns the Facebook comments off.

[image]

The custom post type is **music**.

```
function on_music_publish( $post_ID ) {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_disable_fbc', 'on' );
}
add_action(  'publish_music',  'on_music_publish', 10, 2 );
```

How can I make the following function work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with this type of solution.  It seems to be working fine for me.  I am open on ways to improve this code as it seems there is a better hook that could be used.

```
function on_music_publish( $post_ID, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'music' ) {
        return;
    }
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_disable_fbc', 'on' );
}
add_action(  'save_post',  'on_music_publish', 10, 2 );
```